# Rails: Self joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying design a model which has relation to itself

Model:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many   :positions
  has_many   :sub_departments, class: 'Department', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateDepartments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :departments do |t|
      t.string     :name
      t.references :parent, index: true
      t.references :organization, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `Department.first.sub_departments` I get an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'relation_delegate_class' for "Department":String`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This line `class: 'Department'` should be `class_name: 'Department'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `class_name:` instead of `class:`.